# error in window.location.href = "{% url 'pdfcertificate:pdf_certificate' pk='data.verification_code' %}";

Tags: javascript, url, redirect

I am facing an issue like ,
Page not found (404)
No Certificate matches the given query.

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdf-certificate/data.verification_code/

Raised by:  pdfcertificate.views.pdf_certificate

Using the URLconf defined in certificate.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='create_certificate']

pdf-certificate/str:pk/ [name='pdf_certificate']

Instead of the url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdf-certificate/data.verification_code/' , I have to get the verification code .

In console data.verification code is getting.

Javascript code is

`fetch('', {

```
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}', // Include the CSRF token in the request headers
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                // Show SweetAlert on success
                swal({
                    title: data.title,
                    text: data.message,
                    icon: "success",
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // const verification_code= verification_code;
                    console.log("verification code",data.verification_code);
                    // Redirect to another page after showing the success message
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'pdfcertificate:pdf_certificate' pk='data.verification_code' %}";
                });
            } else {
                // Show SweetAlert on error
                swal({
                    title: "Form Validation Error",
                    text: data.message,
                    icon: "error",
                });
            }
        })`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by,

```
window.location.href = `/pdf-certificate/${verification_code}`;
```